# Convert html to object with based on formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the text inside of the `<strong>` as the `key` in a javascript object, and the text after, up until the next strong, as the `value`, such that the following html would look like this:

```
var jsObj = {  
   "Location(s)":[  
      "Seattle, WA"
   ],
   "Cost":[  
      "$1,500 - $10,000 (see below for details)"
   ],
   "Possible Discounts":[  
      "NA"
   ]
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>
    <strong>Location(s): </strong>
</p>
<p>
    - Seattle, WA
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Cost:</strong>
    $1,500 - $10,000 (see below for details)
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Possible Discounts:</strong>
    N/A
</p>
```

As you can see, there are issues with the formatting where sometimes the text I want is in a completely different `<p>` and other times it is just outside of the strong but inside the same `<p>`

I have been trying to make use of [nextUntil](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

```
var myArr = [];
$('h2').first().each(function(){
    var thisObj = {};
    thisObj.name = $(this).text().trim()
    thisObj.content = [];

    var self = $(this);
    var contents = self.nextUntil('h2');

    contents.each(function(){
        //console.log($(this).text())
        thisObj.content.push($(this).text().trim())
    })

    myArr.push(thisObj)
});
```

Comment: without a guaranteed DOM structure you are a bit stuck...the best way would be to add classes to each of your DOM elements to make it easy on yourself for parsing...

Comment: could you post a JSFiddle of what you've got so far?

Comment: Can  you provide your JS/jQuery logic with th rest of your code?

Comment: Try to add id or classes to your DOM structure so you can easily change/find the correct element

Comment: I've added what I have so far. There is an h2 before each section, which is what I'm using the nextUntil to grab all of the middle content, which is the html that I've posted.

Comment: There are hundreds of pages that have this formatting, so editing the DOM structure is not easy.